# Delete GCP Spanner Instance using dotnet core \ c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I'm trying to find an example of how to delete a GCP Spanner Instance using dotnet core \ C# library.

This provides an example of how to create an instance, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete an instance via code.
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-create-instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the API documentation and guidelines, below code snippet should work.

```
public class DeleteInstanceSample
{
   public Instance DeleteInstance(string projectId, string instanceId)
   {
    // Create the InstanceAdminClient instance.
    InstanceAdminClient instanceAdminClient = InstanceAdminClient.Create();

    InstanceName instanceName = InstanceName.FromProjectInstance(projectId, instanceId);
    
    instanceAdminClient.DeleteInstance(instanceName);

    Console.WriteLine("Instance deleted successfully.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure what I was doing.

Comment: Seems like there are quite a few snippets available for future reference:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/4d3cb646d80630404e45a6b15d344683ef19dd9b/apis/Google.Cloud.Spanner.Admin.Instance.V1/Google.Cloud.Spanner.Admin.Instance.V1.Snippets/InstanceAdminClientSnippets.g.cs#L1086-L1171

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful